# Field set standard UI over my VF page

Tags: object

Hi I want to display the field set standard UI over my VF page. Is it possible to get it over my VF page. Please let me know if possible how can it be done.

Comment: What do you mean with "standard UI"? A field set is a group of fields and have no any UI. What have you tried so far, any code?

Comment: I mean to have the UI where we drag and drop the fields to fieldset to get visible. I am trying to get that UI there.

Comment: Wow, why? Any reason for that, just curious? I mean it is normally an admin job and he have an access to the standard layout UI.

Comment: For me my clint have created some fieldset over a some object and he need it to be displayed over a VF page that want I have done but he want that when he see the page he want to see all the object and can when he select the object all the fieldset should be display and he need to edit the field set there no going to every object. This is what the scenario is. I am bit conduced over this. Can you please help me out.

Comment: I think you are out of luck. I am not sure you can even read a fieldset per SOQL and even more do any DML on it.

Comment: we can read the fieldset and get the field from it and can generate a dynamic SOQL and we can do dml operation after this too this much i have done but got stuck with this UI issue.

Comment: How would you add new fields to the fieldset technically, to which object? I don't think you can modify Schema object.

Comment: I am not want to modify any object. The think is that I need the access to the fieldset UI where er drag and drop fields on my VF page without going to a object field set standard UI.